# Issue in Hive-0.14.0 Integration in HBase-0.98.8-hadoop2

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have hive 0.14.1 hbase 0.98.8 and hadoop 2.5.0 I am trying to integrate hive with hbase and put zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,hbase-common-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar file from HBase/lib to Hive/lib. Steps Followed are as follows:

```
1.hive --auxpath $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.14.1.jar,$HIVE_HOME/lib/hbase-common-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar,$HIVE_HOME/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,$HIVE_HOME/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar -hiveconf hbase.master=masternode:60000

2.CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

This Command does not works for me.It give me error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$Scan$Builder.setCaching(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/ClientProtos$Scan$Builder;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.fullScan(MetaReader.java:542)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.tableExists(MetaReader.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$Scan$Builder.setCaching(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/ClientProtos$Scan$Builder;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toScan(ProtobufUtil.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.RequestConverter.buildScanRequest(RequestConverter.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:117)
    ... 40 more
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the `hbase-protocol` JAR to the classpath.  The symbol that could not be resolved per your stack trace appears to come from there, at least based on cursory inspection only.

Comment: You want to say that i just add hbase-protocol-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar file to Hive/lib folder and add it to --aux path ?